# Check if a string is substring of another string using Swift 5

Tags: swift

Swift5 doesn't have 'contains' method to check for substring any longer. Do you have any other means to find out the same using pure Swift.

```
let input1 = "aabbccddeeaa"
let input2 = "deea"

func isSubstring(input1: String, input2: String) -> Bool {
----
}
```

Comment: `String` still has the `contains` method in Swift 5.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.contains(other: StringProtocol)`. This let's you do something like:

```swift
import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

let result = str.contains("Hello") // true
```

which you can integrate in your function.

Comment: it doesn't work in Swift 5 for String. It works only for characters
func contains(_ element: Character) -> Bool

Comment: @ankykush This answer works just fine in Swift 5. Please explain why you think it does not.

Comment: The referred instance method is actually defined on `StringProtocol` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126753-contains

Comment: Please try it on xcode 10.2.1 playground open and paste the code. Xcode throws error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element(aka Character)'"

Comment: It works for me on Swift 5.0.1. Try running `swift --version` in your terminal to make sure you're running the latest version.

Comment: @ankykush If it's not working for you in Swift 5+, make sure you `import Foundation`

Answer (score 1):

substring works fine. I was missing "import Foundation" on the playground. Once I added the import it was running fine.

Comment: Congrats! Good answer :)